# I am tryint to write a mergesort in python , but the output was different when I input different list

Tags: mergesort

When my input is[6,5,4,3,2,1],the output is [1,2,3,4,5,6],

but when my input is[1,2,3,4,5,6],the output will become [1,1,1,1,1,1].

if there is a number that bigger than the number before it,the output will become wrong

```
def merge (arr,low,mid,high):    
        L=arr[low:mid+1]
        R=arr[mid+1:high+1]
        i=0
        j=0
        k=low
        while i<len(L) and j<len(R):
            if L[i]<=R[j]:
                arr[k]=L[i]
                i+=1
                k+=1
            else:
                arr[k]=R[j]
                j+=1
                k+=1
        while i<len(L):
            arr[k]=L[i]
            i+=1
            k+=1
        while j<len(R):
            arr[k]=L[j]
            j+=1
            k+=1

def sort (arr,low,high):
    if low<high:
        mid=low+(high-low)//2
        print(mid)
        sort(arr,low,mid)
        sort(arr,mid+1,high)
        merge(arr,low,mid,high)

arr=[1,2,3,4,5]
print(arr)
sort(arr,0,len(arr)-1)
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem here:

```
        while j<len(R):
            arr[k]=R[j]    # this was arr[k]=L[j]
```

Typically merge sort has high set to ending index = 1 + last index. This means that sort will need to check for (high - low) > 1, but it eliminate the +1's.

```
def merge (arr,low,mid,high):    
        L=arr[low:mid]
        R=arr[mid:high]
        i=0
        j=0
        k=low
        while i<len(L) and j<len(R):
            if L[i]<=R[j]:
                arr[k]=L[i]
                i+=1
                k+=1
            else:
                arr[k]=R[j]
                j+=1
                k+=1
        while i<len(L):
            arr[k]=L[i]
            i+=1
            k+=1
        while j<len(R):
            arr[k]=R[j]
            j+=1
            k+=1

def sort (arr,low,high):
    if (high - low) > 1:          # if < 2 elements, nothing to do
        mid=low+(high-low)//2
        sort(arr,low,mid)
        sort(arr,mid,high)
        merge(arr,low,mid,high)

arr=[3,2,1,5,4]
print(arr)
sort(arr,0,len(arr))              # len(arr) = ending index of arr
print(arr)
```